# How can I download and show images first in the visible cells from URL quickly and prefetch for next cells?

Tags: ios, swift, prefetch, kingfisher

I have to display multiple images in a `UICollectionView` that contains small logos. When the page is loaded, I want to show logos instantly like in Netflix or any other app, and when I scroll down, the images are shown instantly too. I'm using the `Kingfisher` library to download images from the URL in my `UICollectionViewCell`, but I'm open to accept any other approach that is better.

After hitting the API, when I reload the `UICollectionView` with the response data, I display images like this:

```swift
static let p = ResizingImageProcessor(referenceSize: .init(width: 100, height: 100), mode: .aspectFit) // Processor to resize image to 100 * 100 so download is faster

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return carModels.count
}
    
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:"CarModelCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CarModelCollectionViewCell
        
    let data = carModels[indexPath.row]
        
    cell.ivCar.kf.indicatorType = .activity // added this later as images were taking long to download
    cell.ivCar.kf.setImage(with: data.image, options: [.downloadPriority(1),.processor(CarModelViewController.p), .transition(.fade(0.2))])
        
    return cell
}
    
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, prefetchItemsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
    var carLogoUrlArray = [URL]()
    for indexPath in indexPaths {
        guard let url = carModels[indexPath.row].image else { return }
        carLogoUrlArray.append(url)
    }
    ImagePrefetcher(urls: carLogoUrlArray, options: [.processor(CarModelViewController.p), .downloadPriority(0.75)]).start()
}
```

When I run this code, it still takes too long to download images as images start downloading after the `UICollectionView` is reloaded. Is there any way to make the download faster using the `Kingfisher` library or any other library?

Also prefetching seems to work fine but is it the correct way to download URLs in advance?

My code gets the job done, but I would like to have images downloaded instantly like Netflix or Twitter, where even high quality images are downloaded instantly.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

`.cacheOriginalImage` as one of the options given to Kingfisher

and

`placeholder` as an added parameter to the setImage

Comment: I don't need placeholder in most cases but I tested with .cacheOriginalImage and loading is much faster. Do I add .cacheOriginalImage in my prefetch method too? or just in cellForItemAt? Also should I keep my other options like downloading priority and process in both cellForItemAt and prefetch methods?